# cakephp+Jquery : show and hide forms

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp, show-hide

I'm trying to do all of this on button click so I decided to use jquery.
The scenario is, if FORM1 is visible hide FORM2 vice versa.
Meaning the two forms should never be seen together.
By the way I'm using cakephp.

Form1 Code(visible):

Cakephp

```
echo $this->Form->create('Form1');
....content etc....
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Html equivalent

```
<form id="Form1">
....content etc....
</form>
```

Form2 Code(hidden):

Cakephp

```
echo $this->Form->create('Form2',array('style'=>'display:none;'));
....content etc....
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Html equivalent

```
<form id="Form2" style="display:none;>
....content etc....
</form>
```

Now this is my jquery

```
$('#Btn').click(function(){
    console.log("functions working");
    $('#Form1').hide();
    if ($('#Form2').is(':hidden')) {
    console.log("I entered if");
      $('#Form2').show();
    }
});
```

I just dont get why it doesn't show, I tried to add console logs and they are working fine.
What happens currently is it just hides Form1 and doesn't show Form2.
appreciate all the help tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to successfully hide Form1 and show Form2 ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2675tc9/)). The only change I made is adding the missing quotation marks after the style on your Form2 div, but that might just be a typo on your part.

You could also use the [.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function for more concise code:

```
$('#Btn').click(function(){
    $("#Form1, #Form2").toggle();
}
```